# Select all reverse relations Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

My models are like this:

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', models.DO_NOTHING)

class CreditStatus(models.Model):
    status    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    credit_id = models.ForeignKey('Credit', models.DO_NOTHING)

class CreditCommision(models.Model):
    comission    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    credit_id = models.ForeignKey('Credit', models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Is it possible to select all these tables in one query?
Please note that I can't change Credit model.

I tried:

```
CreditStatus.objects.select_related('credit').filter(status='ACTIVE')
```

But it select only 2 tables, but I need to select all?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
CreditStatus.objects.select_related(
    'credit'
).filter(status='ACTIVE').prefetch_related('credit__creditcommision')
```

This will bring all credit commissions al place them within `all`. so for example

```
credit_statuses = CreditStatus.objects.select_related(
    'credit'
).filter(status='ACTIVE').prefetch_related('credit__creditcommision')

for credit_status in credit_statuses:
    for commission in credit_status.creditcommision.all():
        print(commission)
```

will run only hit the database only twice, once to get the credit statuses with their credits, and a second that will bring all the credit commissions associated with the filtered credit statuses.

You check the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)